# Laravel 4 : Can t execute in php variable sent to view

Tags: php, view, laravel

Hi i ve got problem with executing that variable `<?php echo $show?>` which i sent in my OrderingController with action going_back

```
public function going_back(){
    return View::make('index', array('show' => 'TRUE'));
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this ?

Comment: You should also specify what kind of problem you have - error, behavior and so.

Comment: So show your index.blade.php template, and what you actually get rendered in the markup

Comment: Invalid request (Unexpected EOF- this error show up), when i delete '<?php echo $show ?>' my website shows up. So beside this it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
<?php echo $show ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'; ?>
```

If you are using Blade, You could alternatively,

```
{{ $show ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your controller function:-

```
public function going_back()
{
    $show=True;
    return View::make('test')->with('show',$show);
}
```

Now in view try this:

```
{{$show? $show:false}}
```

It will return 1 if $show is true.

If it do not work,means there is another issue in your view. Paste your view code for better solution.